# takes a word/combo of numbers/sentences and displays duplicate letters

Tags: python, performance, beginner, python-3.x

I am fairly new to coding and was wondering of any tips to improve the code, sorry if it's a pain to read, thanks :)

```
def answer_type():
    print("Would you like to check for duplicate characters in a : word, numbers, sentence?")
    answer = input(">").upper()
    
    if answer == "WORD" or answer == "W":
        finding = "word"
        Type = "letters"
        
    elif answer == "NUMBERS" or answer == "N":
        finding = "numbers"
        Type = "numbers"
        
        
    elif answer == "SENTENCE" or answer == "S":
        finding = "sentence"
        Type = "letters"
        
    return finding , Type
        
        
def get_sent(finding):
    print(f"Please enter your {finding}")
    sentence = input(">")
    
    return sentence
    

def sort_sent(sentence):
    sort_sent = sorted(sentence) 
    amo = len(sort_sent)
    for x in range(amo):
        if sort_sent[0] == " ":
            sort_sent.remove(" ")
            amo = len(sort_sent)
        
        elif sort_sent[0] == ",":
            sort_sent.remove(",")
            amo = len(sort_sent)
            

        else:
            break
       
    return sort_sent ,amo



def duplicate(amo, fin_sent):
    index = 1
    before = 0
    dupe_count = 1
    has_dupe = False
    duplicate_cha = ["" for x in range(amo)]
    for x in range(amo):
        if index == amo:
            break

        
        if fin_sent[x] == fin_sent[index]:
            duplicate_cha[x] = fin_sent[x]
            has_dupe = True
            
            
            
            if before == -1:
                pass
            
            
        elif has_dupe == True:
            pass
        
        else:
            has_dupe = False
        
        index = index + 1
        
        
    duplicate_cha = sorted(duplicate_cha) 
    for x in range(amo):
        if duplicate_cha[0] == '':
            duplicate_cha.remove('')
            amo = len(duplicate_cha)
            
        else:
            break
             
    for x in range(amo):
        
        if amo == dupe_count:
            break
        
        if duplicate_cha[dupe_count] == duplicate_cha[before]:
            duplicate_cha.remove(duplicate_cha[before])
            dupe_count = dupe_count - 1
            before = before - 1
            amo = len(duplicate_cha)
            
            
            
            
        dupe_count = dupe_count + 1
        before = before + 1
        
    return duplicate_cha, has_dupe
        

def print_sent(sentence, choice, Type, dupe, has_dupe):
    if has_dupe == True:
        print(f"Your {choice} '{sentence}' has duplicate {Type}")
        print(f"the {Type} that had a duplicate are {dupe}")
            
       
    elif has_dupe == False:
        print(f"Your {choice} '{sentence}' doesn't have duplicate {Type}")
            
    
def main():
    choice, Type = answer_type()
    sentence = get_sent(choice)
    fin_sent, amo = sort_sent(sentence)
    dupe, has_dupe = duplicate(amo, fin_sent)
    print_sent(sentence, choice, Type, dupe, has_dupe)

    
    
main()
```

Answer (score 3):

You can simplify your `answer_type` and strengthen its types by using an `Enum` that only pays attention to the first letter of the response. This can also encapsulate what you now call "finding" and "type" into one object.

Add PEP484 type hints.

It doesn't make much sense to ask whether the user is going to be providing a word, a sentence or numbers, since your logic treats them all equally.

Sorting is not necessary, and your duplicate calculation is *way* more complicated than it needs to be. Consider using `Counter` instead.

Add a `__main__` guard.

### Suggested

```
from collections import Counter
from enum import Enum
from typing import Iterator, Iterable


class AnswerType(Enum):
    WORD = 'W'
    NUMBERS = 'N'
    SENTENCE = 'S'

    @property
    def element_name(self) -> str:
        return {
            AnswerType.WORD: 'letters',
            AnswerType.NUMBERS: 'numbers',
            AnswerType.SENTENCE: 'letters',
        }[self]


def answer_type() -> AnswerType:
    answer = input(
        "Would you like to check for duplicate characters in a: (w)ord, (n)umbers, (s)entence? "
    )

    return AnswerType(answer[:1].upper())


def get_sentence(type_: AnswerType) -> str:
    return input(f"Please enter your {type_.name.lower()}: ")


def get_duplicates(sentence: str) -> Iterator[str]:
    for c, n in Counter(sentence).items():
        if n > 1 and c not in {' ', ','}:
            yield c


def print_sentence(type_: AnswerType, sentence: str, dupes: Iterable[str]) -> None:
    print(f"Your {type_.name.lower()} '{sentence}'", end=' ')
    dupes = tuple(dupes)
    if dupes:
        print(f"has duplicate {type_.element_name}")
        print(f"The {type_.element_name} that had a duplicate are {', '.join(dupes)}")
    else:
        print(f"doesn't have duplicate {type_.element_name}")


def main() -> None:
    type_ = answer_type()
    sentence = get_sentence(type_)
    dupes = get_duplicates(sentence)
    print_sentence(type_, sentence, dupes)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

### Output

```
Would you like to check for duplicate characters in a: (w)ord, (n)umbers, (s)entence? se
Please enter your sentence: 142654
Your sentence '142654' has duplicate letters
The letters that had a duplicate are 4
```